# Call log always shows '13' missed calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, call-history

I am using Samsung Galaxy S III. My call log always shows '13' missed calls. I tried with restarting the phone etc., But no change. Is there any way to fix the issue without resetting the phone?

Comment: Have you checked out that there is no broken  or un-read message in inbox. Also try a third party message app like `GO SMS/Handcent SMS` from play store and check if they reolve the problem. Also when have you get started this notification?

Comment: Sorry. The question is for my friend. Its not related with message, but call log.

Comment: Is there an alternate dialer app installed?  [Go Contacts Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro) on my wife's Galaxy S II (running Jelly Bean, and previously ICS) is having the same issue.  Opening up the stock Phone app and going to the Call Log tab resets the "stuck" missed calls counter.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to **Settings** > **Application Manager** > **All applications**
   (in the tabs across the top).
2. Check in Downloaded, Running and All
3. Locate and tap the **BadgeProvider** app.
4. Tap <kbd>Clear data</kbd> to reset the counter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

I went to the phone icon and then went to logs, then clicked on "view by miss call" in the top. I deleted all the missed calls by putting a check mark on each on. That fixed my issue and the missed calls on my phone icon got removed.